# Chemical measurement questions

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I have some basic chemical measurement questions. I have to mix 3% of potassium sulfate with calcium sulfate as an accelerant. How do I calculate the 3%? Base it off 100%? Does this question make sense?

Also, I need to measure out 5cc amounts of powder from a large bucket of powder. Is there a measuring cup for cubic centimeters?

Comment: Who has you measuring chemical powders by volume? The amount of chemical you'd get would be highly dependent on how much settling of the powders there is. I'd *highly* recommend looking at the source material for your protocol, and seeing if there's a weight equivalent for the 5cc listed anywhere. Measuring powders by volume is only suitable for low-accuracy tasks like cooking.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Appreciate the insight

Answer (score 1):

Generally a specification like 3% of potassium sulfate is wt%. Such a solution would have 30 g in a about a liter of water (weighing 1 kilogram). $$30/1030 = 2.91 \%$$ which should be close enough. You could use 970 g of water to be more exact. But just filling a beaker to the 1 liter mark would work fine.

I never though of cooking in Europe, but I'd guess that they do have measuring spoons in some $\mathrm{cm}^3$ (mL) units. Again good enough would almost certainly work. $$ 1 \text{ teaspoon} = 4.92892 \text{ mL}$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Appreciate the insight